# How to add python interpreter to Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to add the python interpreter to VSCode as it shows an error. [image: Error given]

Every time I click on this error message to add the interpreter it will show me which interpreters I can select. When I select one of these nothing happens and the same error still shows.[image: Selection of interpreter]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both VSCode and python 3.10 also tried python 3.9 but neither works.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the python extension? Or install another version of the python extension?

Comment: I have reinstalled the python extension yet there is no change. I also just tried 4 previous versions and the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette, run command `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` and add the interpreter setting by hand:

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "path\to\your\python.exe"
```

Comment: This does work thank you (python runs). However is the select python interpreter problem still shows, do you know if this is possible to fix?

Comment: Oh, that is strange. I have no idea, sorry!